# Devise: Is it possible to NOT send a confirmation email in specific cases ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, email-confirmation

Actually I am using devise for login and registration and its working fine, it send a confirmation email which is really good. But I need to send confirmation email in specific cases. I am passing user type in URL and on behalf of that I want to set mail. I have two type of users, one will be confirm their account their self reset of the users can not confirm their account only admin can approve their accounts. I have override the create method

```
def create
    super
    if params[:type]=='xyz
        @user.skip_confirmation_notification!
    end
end
```

but it sends mail in both cases. Please tell where am wrong.

Comment: I think @user.skip_confirmation! will work.

Comment: its working but when I use it then it will not send email, which is good, but it allow to user to login which I don't want.

Comment: I have an another idea, could I set another scope in devise authentication method with status ?

Comment: User is able to login without confirmation?

Comment: I mean can add another scope for confirmation ? such as devise checks confirm_at column, but I want to add another scope as well like (confirm_at!='' && status=true)

Comment: I understand your cases. You can just do it from your model. You can avoid sending confirmation email in many ways. But let me clear you out how easily you can enable user to login without confirming their account. Just check the condition in after_create hook method:
and update the confirmated_at column. This should work.

Comment: @Rubyrider, Can you give me an example..?

Comment: Sure. Let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So according to devise confirmable module you can skip to send confirmation and email by following code.

```
 def confirm_your_type_user_without_confirmation_email
     # check your condition here and process the following
     self.skip_confirmation! 
     self.confirm!
     # condition may end here
 end
```

Now lets call it on create hook.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :confirm_your_type_user_without_confirmation_email
  ....
end
```

for more reference you may check this:
[Devise Confirmable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

The solution should be something similar as I mentioned here above. And its best practice to avoid controller to handle these responsibilities, because its not something your controller should take. :)
I hope my answer will give you some way to solve your problems! Thanks!