# Rails, Devise: is it possible to only confirm email logins and not Facebook logins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have set up Ruby on Rails and Devise using code from [here](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails)

Email logins and Facebook login were all working fine. However, once I configure :confirmable (which creates confirmation emails and user have to click on a URL), Facebook login no longer works. It says Completed 401 Unauthorized in the RoR logs, even though it managed to get a token.

Is there some missing configuration for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The token doesn't care. Devise only checks for the confirmed_at attribute.
But you can just override the confirmation for certain users.

In your user.rb model:

```
protected
def confirmation_required?
  facebook_token.nil? # replace with your own logic.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at another [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986990/devise-is-it-possible-to-not-send-a-confirmation-email-in-specific-cases) on stack overflow. I basically did a `skip_confirmation!` which is defined in [Confirmable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable).